# сократить условие кода

Tags: c, if, логика

я написал код чтобы вычислить функцию , но потом задался вопросом , как написать условие в коде одной строкой ? Может кто подсказать?

```
int main()
{
    double x, y, f;
    printf("Введите x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Введите y: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    if ((x >= 0) && (x < 5))
        printf("получилось %f ", f=2*x-y);
    if (( x<0) && (y<0))
        printf("получилось %f", f= pow(x,2));
    else
        printf("получилось %f", f = 5*y+1);
    printf("Значение функции: %f", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Зачем его писать одной строкой?

Comment: Просто для себя

Comment: Зачем валить всё в одну кучу? Будет всё налеплено и непонятно.

Comment: При данных `(x >= 0) && (x < 5) && (y>=0)` у вас должно выводиться два раза "получилось". Как вы это будете выводить одной строкой?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если я нигде не ошибся (но вроде не должен...), то

```
double x, y;
printf("Введите x: ");
scanf("%lf", &x);
printf("Введите y: ");
scanf("%lf", &y);
int z = (x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0);
double f = z*(2-z)*(2*x-y)+z*(z-1)*(x*x)/2+(z-1)*(z-2)*(5*y+1)/2;
printf("Значение функции: %f", f);
```

Но стало ли от этого понятнее и легче?...

Или даже

```
double f = ((x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0))*(2-(x>=0)*(x<5)-2*(y<0)*(x<0))*(2*x-y)+((x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0))*((x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0)-1)*(x*x)/2+((x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0)-1)*((x>=0)*(x<5)+2*(y<0)*(x<0)-2)*(5*y+1)/2;
```

Убедиться в эквивалентности вашему коду можно тут: https://ideone.com/pfIvea